# Store the result from curl get request for use in another function C++

Tags: c++, curl

Trying to store the data out of the function and use it for another function from res variable, but still to no avail.
Been able to extract the data from the website and looks like this:
`Approximate: 19879888`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#define CURL_STATICLIB
#include <curl/curl.h>




int main()
{
    CURLcode res;
    CURL* curl = curl_easy_init();
    struct curl_slist* header = NULL;

    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl) {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "website for c++ practice");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L);
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    return 0;
}
```

Been searching a lot already but cant find a direct answer. Help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I've never used libcurl, but a couple of minutes flicking around the documentation turns up https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_WRITEDATA.html or https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION.html as a pretty reasonable place where I would begin.

Comment: https://curl.se/libcurl/c/getinmemory.html

Comment: @RemyLebeau I tried the one in the docs and I got this: 29 bytes retrieved. But I want the result so I can practice with them.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION`](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION.html) and [`CURLOPT_WRITEDATA`](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_WRITEDATA.html) options to save the content to a variable, eg:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

#define CURL_STATICLIB
#include <curl/curl.h>

size_t write_callback(char *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userdata)
{
    size_t total = size * nmemb;
    static_cast<string*>(userdata)->append(ptr, total);
    return total;
} 

int main()
{
    CURL* curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl) {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "website for c++ practice");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_callback);

        string data;
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &data);

        CURLcode res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        // use res and data as needed...

        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }

    return 0;
}
```